# How to control Network Activity Indicator on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, networking

I know that in order to show/hide the throbber on the status bar I can use

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
```

But my program sends comm requests from many threads, and I need a location to control whether the throbber should be shown or hidden.

I thought about a centralized class where every comm request will register and this class will know if one-or-many requests are currently transferring bytes, and will turn the throbber on, otherwise - off.

Is this the way to go? why haven't Apple made the throbber appear automatically when networking is happening

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
static NSInteger __LoadingObjectsCount = 0;

@interface NSObject(LoadingObjects)

+ (void)startLoad;
+ (void)stopLoad;
+ (void)updateLoadCountWithDelta:(NSInteger)countDelta;

@end

@implementation NSObject(LoadingObjects)

+ (void)startLoad {
    [self updateLoadCountWithDelta:1];
}

+ (void)stopLoad {
    [self updateLoadCountWithDelta:-1];
}

+ (void)updateLoadCountWithDelta:(NSInteger)countDelta {
    @synchronized(self) {
        __LoadingObjectsCount += countDelta;
        __LoadingObjectsCount = (__LoadingObjectsCount < 0) ? 0 : __LoadingObjectsCount ;

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = __LoadingObjectsCount > 0;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Made it thread safe

Comment: Old question, but still: this solution is not thread-safe, race conditions could cause indicator to be shown even when no network activity is really performed (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Having some logic in your `UIApplication` subclass singleton seems like the natural way to handle this.

```
//@property bool networkThingerShouldBeThrobbingOrWhatever;
// other necessary properties, like timers
- (void)someNetworkActivityHappened {
    // set a timer or something
}
- (void)networkHasBeenQuietForABit
    // turn off the indicator.
    // UIApplcation.sharedApplication.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```